# Add custom field with multiple values to Contact Form 7 and Form Processor

Tags: custom-fields, form-processor

I can't seem to make a custom field that allows multiple values work if more than one value is selected in Contact Form 7 via Form Processor. If one value is selected, everything works fine. If more than one value is selected, Form Processor fails and no contact is created.

This error is logged: Notice: Undefined index: title in Civi\FormProcessor\Type\OptionGroupType->getConfigurationSpecification() (line 40 of /var/www/html/sites/default/civicrm/extensions/form-processor/Civi/FormProcessor/Type/OptionGroupType.php).

Here is my [contact form](https://wildsight.ca/newsletter-test/) (it uses checkboxes). In Form Processor, I have a Custom Options input, with multiple selected and I have the same options set up there.

If I use Try out in Form Processor, it works fine, so I wonder if Form Processor is expecting the data in a different form than Contact Form 7 is sending it in.

Comment: Yes, it looks like Contact Form 7 is sending a list like "A, B, C" and the API wants an array like ["A","B","C"]

Comment: Issue on the plugin: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/api-call-includes-list-for-multi-select-or-checkboxes-api-expects-array/

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you could also develop a new type of input in the Form Processor that deals with the comma separated list.